# Jersey resource @PreDestroy not getting called when Grizzley server is shut down

Tags: jersey-2.0, server-sent-events, grizzly

I'm running a simple Jersey/Grizzly HTTP server with a resource to handle *server-sent events*.

That resource needs to manually take care of a `Timer` instance to send some keep-alive data to all connected SSE clients, so I use `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` annotations to construct and cancel that timer (and its background thread).

The application is a simple console application and not embedded in any container environment like Tomcat. After starting the web server it waits for a simple `System.in.read()` and shuts the server down again by calling [shutdownNow()](http://static.javadoc.io/org.glassfish.grizzly/grizzly-http-server/2.3.28/org/glassfish/grizzly/http/server/HttpServer.html#shutdownNow()) on the Grizzly HTTP server instance.

When connecting to the SSE resource, the resource class in instantiated and the timer is started. After disconnecting from the server, after a short delay the resource is destroyed again and everything is fine.

But due to the nature of the SSE resource a client could possibly be connected endlessly, thus also internally keeping the resource instance around.

If I now try to shutdown the server by calling `shutdownNow()` while a client is connected, the server instance properly shuts down, but does not call any `@PreDestroy` methods of active resources. This causes my resource with the `Timer` instance to stick around and because the timer is still active, this in return keeps the java process running, even though the HTTP server has already been shut down.

**Is there any way to retrieve all currently active resource instances, so I could manually call their respective destroy method prior to shutting down the HTTP server?** Or could this be a bug in the resource instance management of the Grizzly server?

The versions used are:

- jersey-container-grizzly2-http: 2.27
- grizzly-http-server: 2.4.0 (dependency from above)

This is a boiled down version of the code:

```
public class ServerSentEventResource {
    @Context
    private Sse sse;
    private volatile SseBroadcaster broadcaster;
    private final Timer timer = new Timer();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        broadcaster = sse.newBroadcaster();
        final TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            // ...
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        timer.cancel();
        broadcaster.close();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public void get(@Context final SseEventSink eventSink) {
        broadcaster.register(eventSink);
    }
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
    resourceConfig.register(ServerSentEventResource.class);

    HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create("0.0.0.0:8888"), resourceConfig);
    System.in.read();
    server.shutdownNow();

    // At this point there is still the resource instance around, keeping the timer running, thus keeping the JVM running :(
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. I was able to work around the problem by removing the default network listener before actually shutting down the server...

```
httpServer.removeListener("grizzly");
```